# How to set the background color of Customview(NSView)in mac applications?

Tags: ios, macos

I have tried to change the background color of NSView like this in iOS,

```
self.titleview.backgroundcolor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But no property like that exists so after it, I tried,

```
self.titleBarView.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor redColor]set];
```

But it shows some error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  self.titleBarView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
```

If you do not want to use view.layer. You can use NSBox (with custom style) over NSView. NSBox has fillColor property.

Comment: Set 

         [self.titleBarView setWantsLayer:YES]; before using above line